# ASP Net Web Form Web API - FormData is empty if file is attached

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api, multipartform-data

I am using Asp net web form 4.5.1 and Asp net web Api and I trying to send some data and file to Web Api method,
my code is based on `[http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/sending-html-form-data,-part-2][1]` example
but I want to send data via AJAX (jquery)

```
var formData = new FormData();
                var opmlFile = $('#packFile')[0];
                formData.append("opmlFile", opmlFile.files[0]);
                formData.append("packageData",  JSON.stringify(ko.mapping.toJS(this.selectedItem)));

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/api/MyController/MyMethod",                   
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: formData,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function (response) {

                    },
                    failure: function (response) {

                    }
                });
```

it seems like working case, but if I send file with in request my object data is not available(provider.FormData.AllKeys ). How to make it works ? of course I can send 2 request but it is seems not good for me.

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> MyMethod()
    {
        // Check if the request contains multipart/form-data.
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }

        string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
        var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

        // Read the form data and return an async task.
        var task = Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider).
            ContinueWith<HttpResponseMessage>(t =>
            {
                if (t.IsFaulted || t.IsCanceled)
                {
                    Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, t.Exception);
                }

                // This illustrates how to get the file names.
                foreach (MultipartFileData file in provider.FileData)
                {
                    Trace.WriteLine(file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName);
                    Trace.WriteLine("Server file path: " + file.LocalFileName);
                }

                foreach (var key in provider.FormData.AllKeys)
                {
                    foreach (var val in provider.FormData.GetValues(key))
                    {
                        Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", key, val));
                    }
                }

                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            });

        return await task;

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here your multipart request is having JSON + file data, where as `MultipartFormDataStreamProvider` expects form data + file...an example of how a typical multipart formdata request looks like...notice the header called `Content-Disposition: form-data`...

```
POST http://localhost:50460/api/values/1 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------41184676334
Content-Length: 29278

-----------------------------41184676334
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="caption"

Summer vacation
-----------------------------41184676334
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image1"; filename="GrandCanyon.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

(Binary data not shown)
-----------------------------41184676334--
```

For your scenario, you can either create a custom multipart stream provider deriving from the abstract `MultipartStreamProvider` or you can do something like below:

```
Customer customer = null;
foreach(HttpContent content in provider.Contents)
{
    if(content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType == "application/json")
    {
        customer = await content.ReadAsAsync<Customer>();
        break;
    }
}
```